# NDSolveValue::fembdcc: Cross-coupling of dependent variables is not supported in this version

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method

It seems that Mathematica can't solve differential equation when one of the arguments requires that the value of one variable is equal to the value of the other variable, when I try this I get this error:
NDSolveValue::fembdcc: Cross-coupling of dependent variables in DirichletCondition[wgplus==0.99 wgminus,x==0.] is not supported in this version.
Code:

```
    sol = {wp[x, t], wg[x, t], wgplus[x, t], wgminus[x, t], n1[x, t]}
NDSolveValue[{D[wp[x, t], t] + 
    D[wp[x, t], x] == -1.63*(14.4 - n1[x, t])*wp[x, t], 
  D[wgplus[x, t], t] + 
    D[wgplus[x, t], x] == (2*n1[x, t] - 14.4)*wgplus[x, t] + 
    0.0000004*n1[x, t], 
  D[wgminus[x, t], t] - 
    D[wgminus[x, t], x] == (2*n1[x, t] - 14.4)*wgminus[x, t] + 
    0.0000004*n1[x, t], 
  D[n1[x, t], 
    t] == -0.00166*n1[x, t] - (2*n1[x, t] - 14.4)*
     wg[x, t] + (14.4 - n1[x, t])*wp[x, t], 
  wg[x, t] == wgplus[x, t] + wgminus[x, t], 
  wgplus[0, t] == 0.99*wgminus[0, t], 
  wgminus[1, t] == 0.9*wgplus[1, t], n1[x, 0] == 0, 
  wp[0, t] == 1.02}, {wp, wg, wgplus, wgminus, n1}, {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 
  1}]
ParametricPlot3D[sol, {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

I understand, that mistake lays in

```
wgplus[0, t] == 0.99*wgminus[0, t], 
      wgminus[1, t] == 0.9*wgplus[1, t],
```

but I don't know how to solve it.
Is there any workaround?

Comment: You might try telling `NDSolve` explicitly to use the Method of Lines instead of the Finite Element Method.  If that does not work (and it probably won't), then decomposing the PDEs in `x` into a set of ODEs. as described [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html) may be necessary.  I regret that I do not have time to illustrate the process.  By the way, you may find that someone else has raised this question in the past in Mathematica.StackExchange.